# How do you do this vector projection?

Tags: vectors

For $\textbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\textbf{w} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, compute $\text{proj}_{\textbf{w}} \textbf{v}$.

I don't know how to project vectors of this form... I can only do it in 2D. Is there a formula for this?

Comment: You do it the same way. There are just more components to compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any vector **u** projected onto any vector **v**, take the dot product of **u** with **v** "hat", the unit vector of **v** (found by **v**/|**v**|). This dot product gives the scalar projection, to find the vector projection, simply multiply this scalar magnitude by the unit direction **v** "hat" again.

So for this problem, normalize **w** by its magnitude to obtain **w** "hat", then dot **v** with **w** "hat" to obtain the scalar projection (the magnitude of the vector projection), then just write this scalar times the **w** "hat" direction vector to obtain the complete vector projection expression.